# API to search news by year

Tags: api, search, search-engine, data-mining

I would like to write Python script, which will get i.e. 100 news/texts from year 2011, 2010, 2009, etc. on given topic.

**I need searching API** which will met following requirements:

1. Available for free, exposed as a web service.
2. Returns given amount of objects.
3. Filters by date. Precisely, allows to get objects from given years.
4. Return should contain quite long text (i.e. more than 100 words) which is related to given
   keyword.
5. This text is easy to extract from the whole response.

For example, I tried with [Google Web Search API](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/websearch/docs/):

8 first results from year 2007:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?q=Obama+daterange%3A2454102-2454467&start=0&rsz=8&v=1.0

Points 1 and 2 are fulfilled. Filtering by years is added with not very popular [datarange:](http://reviews.cnet.com/4520-10165_7-6206764-2.html) search operator. Point 5 is ok, because response is JSON. Problem is with point 4, because it returns only short content and title. I have an URL of a page with the full content, but then (after another GET request) it's hard to extract this content from the whole HTML document.

**Do you know such API? Or maybe you have another idea how to tackle this problem?**

Comment: You do not want to index the data yourself, right?

Comment: If yes, I suppose I should write own crawler then. It's an interesting idea, but at this moment no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Guardian (A uk newspaper) are quite good when it comes to making their data available. They even have google doc integration. Check http://www.guardian.co.uk/open-platform out

Do you need the data to be live, or would a simple dataset meet your needs?

Comment: Simple dataset will be ok. That API looks nice, but I don't see that it can return a full content, or some other text long enough to analyse, point 4 of requirements...

Comment: I found that I can GET the whole article page pointed by "webUrl" and after doing some HTML parsing get all text of news, so your answer was helpful, thanks. Akcjept.

Comment: They are very open about data usage.